# how to display test data confusion matrix in matlab (neural networks)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, confusion-matrix

```
>>net = patternnet([100 100]);
>>net = train(net, input_data', target_data');
>>view(net);
>>y = net(input_data');
>>plotconfusion(target_data',y);
```

In this codes,ploted confusion matrix is total confusion matrix, how to get just test data confusion matrix???
[image: generated by toolbox]

[image: generated by code]

Comment: It actually depends on how you did split your dataset. `input_data` I reckon is the training set and `target_data` is the training labels and `y` is the training set predicted labels vector. If I understood correctly, then, `plotconfusion()` matrix is correct (although you should consider also a validation set). You can plot the confusion matrix only thanks to correct and predicted labels. What do you mean by "total confusion matrix"?

Comment: In a more general terms you should have a Training Set and its Training Labels, which you can use to train your classifier. Once the model has ben trained, you should predict the labels for the Validation Set and then create the confusion matrix between the true Validation Labels and such predicted labels.

Comment: In matlab neural network tool box, pattern  recognition app, after training and push plotconfusion button, generate four confusion matrix (training, test,validation,all) , and i said "total confusion matrix" ==> all confusion matrix, and In toolbox, i can use  just1 hidden layer, so i use code for multilayers, but plotconfusion function use , just generate "all confusion matrix"